# ExtJS - submitting disabled checkbox

Tags: extjs

Version 4.2.1

In a form I use a checkbox which should not be changed for a certain type of user.
So I disable the checkbox and set `checked` and `value` to `true. I want this value to be submitted.

```
        {
          name: 'myName',
          itemId: 'myItemId',
          xtype: 'checkboxfield',
          fieldLabel: "test",
          checked: true,
          value: true,
          disabled: true,
        },
```

When I submit the form I see that there is no parameter for this checkbox.
Only when I set disabled to true I get a parameter with value `on`

When I look at:

```
    var data = form.getValues();
    console.log(data);
```

this checkbox is not submitted with an `on` value.

When I use `readonly: true` I can check/uncheck the checkbox and that value is submitted.

So how can I disable the checkbox for editing, set the value to checked and get it submitted to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this thread from 2008/2009 which has a simple solution.

[Form Submit is not sending values of disabled field](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?35941-SOLVED-Problem!-Form-Submit-is-not-sending-values-of-disabled-field..)
[Sending disabled field](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?35949-SOLVED-how-do-you-override-Ext.lib.Ajax)

This code sets the checkbox to readonly is shown and a user cannot change the value.
And the field is submitted to the server.

```
readOnly: true,
fieldClass: "x-item-disabled"
```

Comment: This doesn't work as `readOnly` only add the `readonly` HTML attribute to the checkbox intut field, which is not valid and therefore has no effect.